# Animating UIImageView rotation during UISwipeActionsConfiguration in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, uikit

I am trying to add a swipe action to my UITableView cell with a rotating icon animation. The goal is to have an arrow icon initially pointing up and smoothly rotating to the right during the swipe action. I've attempted to achieve this by using UIContextualAction and rotating the UIImageView associated with the action. However, I'm facing issues with the animation.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    func rotateIcon(angle: CGFloat) {
        for subview in contentView.subviews {
            if let imageView = subview as? UIImageView {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let moreAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "More") { (action, view, completion) in
        // Perform actions when "More" button is tapped
        print("More option selected for item: \(self.items[indexPath.row])")
        // Add your custom actions here

        // Call completion handler to indicate that the action was performed
        completion(true)
    }

    // Customize the appearance of the action button
    moreAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    // Add an image view to the action
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.circle"))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    // Rotate the image view from pointing up to pointing right
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)

    // Add the image view to the action's view
    moreAction.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageView.bounds.size).image { _ in
        imageView.drawHierarchy(in: imageView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }

    let swipeConfiguration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [moreAction])
    return swipeConfiguration
}
```

Despite my efforts, the rotation animation doesn't seem to work as expected. The arrow icon doesn't smoothly rotate from pointing up to pointing right during the swipe action.

Can someone please help me identify what I might be missing or suggest a better approach to achieve this rotating icon effect during a swipe action in a UITableView?

Thank you!

Comment: Not really clear what you're going for... Do you want an "up arrow" to be ***always*** visible at the right side of the cell, and rotate 90-degrees as you drag/swipe the cell to the left? Or, do you want a square button with an "up arrow" to be ***revealed*** as you drag/swipe to the left, with the button rotating as it's revealed?

Comment: I want the up arrow to be animated to point to the right point when user open the menu

Comment: something like LinkedIn mail list

Comment: So, is this the kind of effect you're going for? https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzTwy.gif ... in your question, you show a `rotateIcon(angle: CGFloat)` func, but I don't see you calling it anywhere?